# Maven deploy error

Tags: maven, deployment

I have maven project with several modules. Need to deploy all modules(*jars* and one resulting *war*) into remote Artifactory server.
So in settings.xml I am added config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <id>central</id>
    </server>
    <server>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>password</password>
      <id>snapshots</id>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
           <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Main pom have section:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/libs-release-local</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository> 
        <id>snapshots</id>         
        <url>http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local</url> 
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

And all modules have `1.0-SNAPSHOT` version.
But when executing the command: `>mvn deploy`, the Following error occured:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy
>   (default-deploy) on project jobic: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could
>   not transfer artifact *project-name:project-nam*e:pom:0.0.1 from/to central
>   (http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/libs-release-local): Failed to
>   transfer file:
>   http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/libs-release-local/project-name/project-name/0.0.1/project-name-0.0.1.pom.
>   Return code is: 401 -> [Help 1]

How to deal with it?

**UPDATE:**

Ok, I got it. The 401 error says: 401 = "Unauthorized" . So I added proper username/password into settings.xml. Seems work now.

**Have one last question: it is right, that I am using SNAPSHOT suffix in the version? Is it proper behavior for situation, when I need do deploy all modules onto remote repo? How to deal with situation, when the one module was broken and my coworkers need to use previous version of this module?**

Comment: You have written 'hhttp' yourself in your pom file. Just a typo I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure what you imply when saying module. But if you mean modules like ejb ear test and they all have own snapshots and the one is broken then I think they can be worked with broken one's old snapshot. And of course you must keep all snapshots in your repository and all you must to do is changing broken's snapshot to old one. I hope this would help.

Comment: Module - as a separete project. http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects.
Tnx, anyway.

Comment: Ok. They can have different snapshot versions from each other. Actually I have a project just like you mentioned and some poms' snapshot versions different and project work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because it is written incorrectly.
You can change it hhttp to http and try again.

Comment: yeap, this is my mistake. Fixed this, but now the server returning the 401 error. I will update my question.

Comment: The link >http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/libs-release-local
work fine and show me the list of files
And the link http://192.168.1.120:8088/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local works fine also, but returned _No items found_

Comment: I can't reach both neither. It might works just local or its accessibility options cause the problem. I think you should check second link and look the file you looking for really there is or not.